# Gaussian Mixture Model with Minkowski distance

Tags: clustering, distance, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Gaussian Mixture Models assume Mahalanobis distance (essentially L2). Is it possible to use Lp distance in a GMM?

Intuitively, in 1-space, distance is clear. In 2-space, the relation between the two variables can be thought of via the distance metric (ie. GMM with 1 component can have a mean at (2,2) and some stdev, but the boundary of 1 stdev is different based on the distance metric - see image. For example, a point (1,1) will have lower likelyhood in a L1 distance than in a L2 distance with the same mean, stdev). Similarly, we can extend the 2 dim regime to higher dims. Can we translate this to a Gaussian Mixture Model?

[image: 2D unit balls, Waldir Pimenta, CC BY-SA 3.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0, via Wikimedia Commons]

Answer (score 3):

The Gaussian mixture model assumes a Gaussian (normal) distribution of the observations within mixture components. If you compute a Maximum Likelihood (ML) estimator for a Gaussian distribution, this will involve Mahalanobis distances because they occur in the formula of the multivariate Gaussian density function. This is still true when computing an ML estimator of a Gaussian mixture using the EM-algorithm, however note that unless covariance matrices of the mixture components are assumed equal, the Mahalanobis distances computed within different mixture components are not the same.

Gaussian mixture models are *not* distance-based methods, as they are computed from the original observations rather than from given distances between the observations, so I think it is not appropriate to say that Gaussian mixtures "assume" Mahalanobis distances (although ML-fitting is based on Mahalanobis distances in some sense, see above).

As the Mahalanobis distances arise because of the Gaussian density, you cannot have a mixture of Gaussian distributions using other distances, as these do not arise from the Gaussian distribution (the Euclidean/L2-distribution is involved when assuming all covariance matrices equal and spherical; this is a special case of Mahalanobis).

An interesting question is whether other distances arise in *other* mixture models in the same way as Gaussian mixtures are connected to Mahalanobis. In fact distributions and mixture models can be derived based on general distances, although they may be hard to estimate, and software isn't necessarily available. You may want to have a look at Section 2 of our paper

Hennig, Christian; Viroli, Cinzia; Anderlucci, Laura, Quantile-based clustering, ELECTRONIC JOURNAL OF STATISTICS, 2019, 13, pp. 4849 - 4883, https://dx.doi.org/10.1214/19-EJS1640

where we discuss this and give some references. (Quantile-based clustering is based on an asymmetric discrepancy, a generalised distance, which is a generalisation of the L1-distance allowing for skewness. An R-package for this does exist, named QuClu. I believe that this can be forced to run with the plain L1-distance. Note also that this is technically somewhat different from a mixture model, if closely related.)

Comment: My understanding is that Section 2 of the paper goes into detail about generalizing K-means for different distance metrics rather than a generalization of mixture models for an Lp prior distribution. Is this understanding incorrect?

Comment: K-means is actually an ML-estimator for a fixed partition model with Gaussian distributions and spherical and equal covariance matrices, as such based on squared Euclidean distance, and pretty similar (though not identical) to a mixture model. Sec. 2 says how this can be used with general distances. One can well apply the same idea to mixture models.

Comment: Is there not well defined literature for non-gaussian mixture models? It seems relatively simple to extend for a laplace distribution, or any other Lp prior. Secondarily, is there any package that does this that you are aware of?

Comment: @olivarb Had I been aware of it I'd have told you so. There is a lot of literature on non-Gaussian mixtures and also packages, but most of this is not interested in distances. Standard mixture modelling is based on statistical distributions and doesn't need to involve distances explicitly, so people who come up with work on mixture models start from distributions to mix or problems to solve rather than from distances.

Comment: @olivarb If you don't find anything it may not be so difficult to build your own using R's ```flexmix``` package.

Comment: That makes sense. In the same way that an L1 regularization corresponds to the Laplacian prior and the L2 regularization corresponds to the Gaussian prior, would it be incorrect to assume that, because the data has some Lp distance inherent to the data, we should use the mixture model corresponding to the prior for that p value ($e^{-|x|^p}$)? Why suggest the K means type derivation instead of this path?

Comment: @olivarb The K-means type derivation is computationally easier and much faster. Regarding the other question, any mixture model is based on a distributional assumption within clusters, and the decision to use such a model depends on whether this assumption makes sense for the data in hand. Of course alternatively you can use other distance-based clustering methods. By the way I wouldn't use the terms "prior" or "p-value" here (this is neither a Bayesian prior nor a p-value for a test) and because of this I'm not 100% sure whether what I think you mean is really what you mean.

Comment: What term would you use? I'm also concerned that we may not be talking about the same thing here. For clarification, the p value I'm referring to is not for the p test, but for an order p Minkowski metric. Re prior - when we preform an L2 regularization step, we assume a Gaussian prior and L1 regularization assumes a Laplacian prior. Similarly, we can somewhat extract the prior given the order of a Minkowski metric (in the format $e^{-|x|^p}$ given an order $p$). My question was how one would run a mixture model on this prior. Does this follow?

Comment: OK, "value of p" is clearer than p value but I got that one. Mixture components in mixture models are nowhere called prior as far as I know (unless maybe if used as prior for something else). I now understand your use of prior but this is highly nonstandard. Mixture modelling is very different from regularisation.